# ControllerAdvice with ExceptionHandler and ModelAndView not loading the correct view on screen

Tags: spring, modelandview, exceptionhandler

I need help on this, please take a look at my code:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@EnableWebMvc
public class GlobalExceptionController {

    @ExceptionHandler(CustomGenericException.class)
    public ModelAndView handleCustomException(CustomGenericException ex) {

        // create the model and view with the tiles View pointing to error jsp page
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("pagina.erro");
        model.addObject("errCode", ex.getErrCode());
        model.addObject("errMsg", ex.getErrMsg());

        return model;

    }
...
```

Tiles configuration:

```
<definition name="pagina.erro" extends="baseLayout">
    <put-attribute name="titlepagina" value="Página de Erro" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/error/erro-generico.jsp" />
</definition>
```

In my Spring configuration xml I have:

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The page **erro-generico.jsp** is being loaded because if I put a wrong code in it errors will be shown on eclipse console.

The problem is: the page is not shwowing, the actual page keeps showing on the browser, not even the URL changes.

What could be wrong?

Comment: is the exception handler getting hit, could you post the server logs?

Comment: Yes, the code for the exception handler is being hit and the page is beeing lunched, but not showing, there is nothing on console, the only thing I see is:
Fev 20, 2014 5:18:26 PM org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache tldScanJar
Informações: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the view resolver being used is not compatible with Tiles, it only works for pure JSPs.

It's possible to configure a view resolver for Tiles by following these instructions  - [14.3.2. How to integrate Tiles](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/reference/view.html):

```
bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
  <property name="definitions">
    <list>
      <value>/WEB-INF/defs/general.xml</value>
      <value>/WEB-INF/defs/widgets.xml</value>
      <value>/WEB-INF/defs/administrator.xml</value>
      <value>/WEB-INF/defs/customer.xml</value>
      <value>/WEB-INF/defs/templates.xml</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
  <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: My spring-servlet.xml, also, I had already tried with pure JSP instead of using tiles:
`<bean id="tilesViewResolver"
 class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
 <property name="viewClass"
  value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
 class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
 <property name="viewClass"
  value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
 <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
 <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>`